# Simple jQuery function not called

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is an old web project I have to add some functionality to, and alot was done using plain javascript.

Because I wanted to start using jQuery, I wrote the following simple test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Radiotest</title>
        <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myButton').on('click', function() {
        alert("Test");
        alert($('input[name=Test]:checked', '#myForm').val()); 
    });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="result"></div><br/>
    <form id="myForm">
        <input type="radio" name="Test" value="1"> 1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Test" value="2"> 2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Test" value="3"> 3<br>
        <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Check">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, when clicking on the button after selecting a radio element the function is not being called, or atleast none of the alerts get displayed.

Can you please help me spot the error. Thank you.

Comment: Your browser debugging tools are probably trying to tell you the error.  I bet you're getting a 404 error when requesting the jQuery script, and that error is coming from your own server.  And I bet you're getting a console error saying that `$` is not a function.

Comment: seems to work fine... http://jsfiddle.net/RDCVF/

Comment: @Borik: That's because the error isn't in the JavaScript code, it's in the `script` tag.  Which your version quietly fixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `src` attribute value `ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js` is invalid. You must either include the `http://` or `//` to pickup the currently used protocol:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. My original version had `//` but my browser seems unable to pickup the correct protocol. It might be due to me calling a local html file. Adding the protocol fixed. Will accept your answer ASAP.

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno If you're using your local IP address (e.g., `192.168.1.xx`) it will match the protocol. If you're loading from `localhost`, there is no protocol to match.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case `src="http://resource"`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```